# My PC doesn't wake up from hibernation when I use a new DisplayPort cable

Tags: windows-10, hibernate, dvi, displayport

I built a new PC two months ago. This week, I changed the monitor cable from a DVI one to a DisplayPort one. My problem: The PC won't come back from **auto**-hibernation on Windows 10 Pro. It does come back from **manual**-hibernation.

This is very strange and I could not find any discussion on the same issue.

I've got the following PC parts:

- Motherboard: [Asus TUF Z270 MARK 1 ATX](https://www.asus.com/au/Motherboards/TUF-Z270-MARK-1/specifications/)
- Graphics card: [Quadro K620 2GB (DVI or DisplayPort)](http://www.pny.com/nvidia-quadro-k620)
- Monitor: [BenQ SW2700PT](http://www.benq.com.au/product/monitor/sw2700pt/specifications/)

My guess is the problem might be software rather than hardware. Here are the facts:

- Waking up from an **auto**-hibernation or a **manual**-hibernation works with the DVI cable.
- Waking up from a **manual**-hibernation works with the DP cable.
- To unstuck the PC and get back to my windows session, I have to force a complete shutdown (or see below).
- The PC can wake up normally from an automatic hibernation if I unplug the DP cable from behind the PC **before** powering up the machine. Then, I plug back the cable and see my windows session.

What I did so far:

- Established that the DP cable is working fine.
- Disconnected and reconnected the DP cable.
- Reverse the DP cable direction.
- Ended all background tasks before letting the PC goes into hibernation.
- Shut down the PC completely and unplug the power cable for a couple of seconds to reset every electronic component, then boot up, log into windows and let the PC goes into hibernation.
- Updated the graphics card driver.

Using the DVI cable solves the problem, but I want to use the DP cable to carry the audio to the monitor.

Any idea?

EDIT 1: Added the list of facts and what I did so far.
EDIT 2: Added another fact: "The PC can wake up normally from an automatic hibernation if I unplug the DP cable from behind the PC before powering up the machine. Then, I plug back the cable and see my windows session."

Comment: So I guess you already installed the latest drivers for Graphics?

Comment: @davidbaumann, yes, just now. From v377.17 to v377.35. No change.

Comment: I have added the list of facts and what I did so far.

Comment: Did you try disabling/enabling DP 1.2 on the monitor?

Comment: @JohnKeates, I am not sure what you mean. Can you clarify? I have remarked that when the PC has automatically put into hibernation if I disconnect the DP cable from the PC and press the power button, the PC wake up normally. Then, I can plug the cable back and see my windows session. Weird.

Comment: DisplayPort 1.2 added some extra features, which is problematic with some monitors. The monitor often has settings in the menu to enable/disable 1.2 support. Switching that might help.

Comment: @JohnKeates, I didn't find that option on the monitor. The specifications sheet says the DisplayPort input is v1.2.